# How to Setup GIMP 2.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

Tags: 16.04, gimp

I want to Setup GIMP 2.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) without flatpak.

can it be possible now or on future??

Comment: personally i use gimp 2.9.9 but no big question to install gimp 2.10 with help of ppa

Answer (score 7):

GIMP 2.10 can be installed natively in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by installing the *gimp* snap package. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

This command installs GIMP 2.10 from the stable channel. If you need to have full access to external media (such as USB flash drive, SD/MicroSD card, additional mounted hard drive and so on), run the following command:

```
sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
```

You can also install GIMP 2.10 from the Ubuntu Software app by selecting the GIMP snap package which is called GIMP in Ubuntu Software.

[image]

You can change the interface language in GIMP by selecting *Edit* -> *Preference*s -> *Interface* -> under the **Language** section select a new language from the dropdown menu. Restart GIMP for the changed interface language to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/gimp
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install gimp-devel
```

then run `gimp-devel` to open Gimp 2.10

Answer (score 0):

The snap-thing will lack localization / translation
( snap should stay away from any LTS because of those kinds of lacks )

There's Otto Meier's ppa for the usual way of install :

https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gimp#pour_disposer_des_dernieres_versions_stables

…gimp 2.10 is available there ( with translation / localization ) for 17.10 and 18.04 but beware : before enabling this ppa on your system, first uninstall your actual Gimp 2.8.

I assume it will soon be available for 16.04 ?